# Calculate % cover of an intersected area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I am working on a project for university, I am nearly finished but I have come across a hiccup.

I am trying to calculate the number of people that would be effected by sea level rise. The project is quite basic as it is the first time I have used GIS software (ArcMap 10.4).

Below shows the wards of Brighton (blue) and the sea level rise (pink). I have joined a table from excel to the wards which contains the population data for each ward. Further, I have converted the sea level rise to a polygon (from a raster) so that I could perform an intersect of the two (second picture).

I am sure their must be away to calculate the number of affected people. Either to calculate the %cover of each ward, then take that % of the total number of people. Or

To use the software to tell me how many people have been affected, as it knows the population for each ward?

[image: Wards and Sea level rise]

[image: Intersect]

Comment: So you already have the intersection with an attribute for the population field... What have you tried and what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: to be clear, i am looking for a tool to determine the number of people affected by the sea level rise

Comment: i have tried to use the tabulate intersection tool but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already in your question :). 
You got the area and the population size of your ward. You also got the area of the ward which got flooded. Assuming that population is equally distributed across the ward, all you need to do is

`population * flooded ward area/ ward area`

Afterwards sum up results for each ward.